# How to get last inserted rows where a condition is satisfied

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

table1:

```
esps
--------------
A
B
C
--------------
```

table2:

```
id      _name       esp
------------------------------
1       Ana        A
2       Ana        B
3       Mario      A
4       Jorge      A
5       Jorge      C
6       Ana        A
------------------------------
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 where esp = 'A' group by _name having id = max(id);
```

Query result:

```
id      _name      esp
-----------------------------
3       Mario      A
4       Jorge      A
-----------------------------
```

Expected result:

```
id      _name      esp
-----------------------------
6       Ana        A
3       Mario      A
4       Jorge      A
-----------------------------
```

Any advice or sugestion will be appreciated. Mysql version 8.0.16

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 'last' A:

```
SELECT * FROM table2
    where esp = 'A'
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

If you need something more complicated, see "groupwise-max".

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name 
                                       ORDER BY id DESC) rn 
             FROM table2 
             WHERE esp='A' )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn=1
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that will work for you?

```
SELECT * FROM table2 where esp = 'A' group by _name,esp order by esp desc Limit 1
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table2 where id = (SELECT max(id) FROM table2 where esp = 'A' group by _name)
```

EDIT
This should work

```
SELECT * FROM table2 where esp = 'A' group by _name,esp order by esp desc
```

Comment: I tried your query, but 'Ana's id is 1 instead of the correct 6. Thanks anyway